# Insert two Excel columns in one MySQL table column using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

I have an Excel file that have this form:

> lon      lat     site1      site2
>
> x,x1     y,y1     name1     name2
>
> x,x2     y,y2
>
> x,x3     y,y3     name3     name4
>
> x,x4     y,y4

and so on,
I need to know how to insert it in a MySQL table like in this form

> cord1           cord2         site1       site2
>
> x,x1/y,y1     x,x2/y,y2       name1       name2
>
> x,x3/y,y3     x,x4/y,y4       name3       name4

and so on,
here is the code i used:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "DB";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
@$conexion = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or                 trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);  
mysql_select_db($database, $conexion);
require_once 'PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileName ='FILE.xlsx'; 
try {
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName); // télécherger le fichier 
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'":   '.$e->getMessage());
}
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
$i=0 ;
$j=1 ;
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    $rowData[] = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn .        $row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
}
foreach($rowData as $row) {
foreach($row[0] as $var) {  
 $t[$i]= $var ;
 $i = $i +1 ;   
}   
for($a=1;$a<= $highestRow ;$a+=2){
    $lan1[$a]=$t[0] ;    
    $long1[$a]=$t[1] ;
    $coor1[$i]=$lan1[$a].",".$long1[$a]; 
    } 
for($b=2;$b<= $highestRow ;$b+=2){
    $lan2[$b]=$t[0] ;    
    $long2[$b]=$t[1] ;  
    $coor2[$i]=$lan2[$b].",".$long2[$b]; 
    }
$sql= " INSERT INTO  line    (`coordinates1`,`coordinates2`,`name1`,`name2`,`color`,`interface1`,`interface2`    )         VALUES     ('".utf8_decode($coor1[$i])."','".utf8_decode($coor2[$i])."','".utf8_decode($name1)."','".utf8_decode($name2)."','".utf8_decode($t[3])."','".utf8_decode($interface1)."','".utf8_decode($interface2)."')" ; 
$res=mysql_query($sql, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
$sql2= " DELETE FROM line WHERE name1=''" ; 
$res2=mysql_query($sql2, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());   
 }} 
$i = 0 ;
}
?>
```

the names of variables are not the same. Please, I really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_query` it's deprecated for years and now removed from PHP codebase. PDO has been there since PHP 5.0, use it.

Comment: Well , the querys are working fine , what I realy need is the part where WE create the variables in the "for"  function . It don't insert $coor2 , just $coor1 is replicated in bothe columns.